# Dynamically change chrome.browserAction.onClicked behaviour

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Good day!

I have a simple chrome extension that changes the DOM of a webpage (it sorts comments, to be more precise). I have a **background.js** which contains the code below:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      null, {file : "app.js"});                                                                                                                                                                         
});
```

So **app.js** executes when I click on the extension's icon.

I'd like to reset all changes by clicking on the icon for the second time. Ideally the page would be sorted again if I click on the icon for the third time and so on. Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would reloading the page be acceptable when the icon is clicked the second time? Or do you want to undo all the changes done by app.js without reloading the page?

Comment: @Emily, I can store the initial state of the comment tree, so I'd like to use it, not just reset and reload all.

Comment: Hmm, so if you have a global flag variable, and in your `browserAction.onClicked` handler, call `executeScript` if the flag is false, reset the comments if the flag is true, and then toggle the flag, would that work for you? Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Thank you, @Emily, your vision of the situation is totally correct, I will try to use that way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to have Chrome automatically undo the changes `app.js` has made to the page's DOM, but you can have `app.js` undo its own modifications. Either detect that `app.js` is being run for the second time (set a global variable from the injected script into [your extension's isolated world](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment)) or inject the script once per tab and [send a message](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#event-onMessage) to tell it which state to put the page into.

It looks tricky to inject the script only once per tab without making it a content script, and that would prevent you from using the upcoming [`activeTab`](http://developer.chrome.com/beta/extensions/activeTab.html) permission, so having `app.js` remember is probably better, unless you're already ensuring a single injection for other reasons.

Comment: Thank you, @Jeffrey, I guess that global variables would work for me